# What does even mean in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm working through some homework problems in Papoulis and Pillai. In problem 4-1 it is

Suppose that $x_u$ is the $u$ percentile of the random variable $\textbf{x}$, that is, $F(x_u) = u$. Show that if $f(-x) = f(x)$, then $x_{1-u} = -x_u$.

The given solution relies on "the evenness of $f(x)$" What does that mean?

The solution uses $F(x_u) + F(-x_u) = 1$. How do we know this is true? And what does it mean?

Comment: If $f(-x)=f(x)$ then $f$ is called an even function. If $f(-x)=-f(x)$ then $f$ is called odd. Justify this terminology by inspecting the graphs!

Comment: I've justified the terminology by $x^2, x^4,....$ being even functions and $x^3, x^5,....$ being odd.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that $f=F'$, it is enough to integrate $f(x)-f(-x)=0$ in $x$ to obtain $F(x)+F(-x)=const$, and send $x$ to $+\infty$ to evaluate the constant.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(x) = f(-x)$ implies that $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution (given that $f$ is the density). In particular
$$
u = P(X\leq x_u) =P(-X\leq x_{u}) = P(X\geq-x_u) 
$$
where the second equality is because  $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution. So
$$
1-u = P(X\lt -x_{u}) = P(X\leq -{x_{u}})
$$
where the last equality is because $X$ has a density. So the $1-u$ percentile of $X$ is $-x_{u}$ as desired.